# Use variables from one .as file in another?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

If I have created variables in one document named Main.as as follows:

```
var backgroundLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
var gameLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
var interfaceLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
```

How can I access these in another .as file? I'm trying to sort the objects in my game into layers but I'm getting errors. For example, I have a EnemyShip.as file with the following in it:

```
function enterFrame(e:Event)
        {
            this.x -= speed;
            if(this.x < -100)
            {
                removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
                stage.removeChild(this);
            }
        }

function kill()
        {
            var explosion = new Explosion();
            stage.addChild(explosion);
            explosion.x = this.x;
            explosion.y = this.y;
            removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);
            Main.updateScore(1);
            shot.play();
        }
```

The problem is I was trying to change `stage.addChild(explosion)` to `gameLayer.addChild(explosion)` but I got an `access of undefined property gameLayer` error.

There may be something obvious I am missing, so please let me know. I'm also not too sure whether I should be using `new Sprite` or `new Movieclip`; the majority of my game is made up of movie clips and buttons, so perhaps this should be changed?

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried Kodiak's second solution by doing the following (Relevant parts):

EnemyShip.as:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.Socket;

public class EnemyShip extends MovieClip
{
    public static var gameLayer:Sprite;

    var speed:Number;
    var shot = new ShotSound();

    public function EnemyShip()
    {
        this.x = 800;
        this.y = Math.random() * 275 + 75;
        speed = Math.random()*5 + 9;
        addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseShoot);
    }
```

Main.as:

```
package  {
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.Socket;


public class Main extends MovieClip {

EnemyShip.gameLayer = gameLayer;
var interfaceLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
var menuLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
var endGameLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
```

I'm getting errors like `1120: Access of undefined property gameLayer` on lines such as `EnemyShip.gameLayer = gameLayer;` and when I try to do things like:

```
    crosshair = new crosshair_mc();
    gameLayer.addChild(crosshair);
```

I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Standard

To respect OOP, you should give the game layer to your `EnemyShip` class as a parameter. For example:

```
package
{
   public class EnemyShip extends Sprite
   {
       private var _gameLayer:Sprite;

       public function EnemyShip(pGameLayer:Sprite)
       {
           _gameLayer = pGameLayer;
       }
   }
}
```

and when you instanciate it from your Main.as:

```
var enemy:EnemyShip = new EnemyShip(gameLayer);
```

### Static

Another solution, less trivial but easier to use, would be having a static variable such as:

```
package
{
   public class EnemyShip extends Sprite
   {
       public static var gameLayer:Sprite;

       public function EnemyShip()
       {
           if (!gameLayer)
           {
              throw new Error("Game Layer not defined on EnemyShip");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And in your Main.as:

```
EnemyShip.gameLayer = gameLayer; //once and for ever
var enemy:EnemyShip = new EnemyShip();
var enemy2:EnemyShip = new EnemyShip();
```

Comment: I have quite a few functions so I guess I'll have to do this for them all? I basically want to create layers for the background (Scrolling background for the game), game (Crosshairs, ships) and interface layer (Score, timer etc.) and maybe another one for the menu or I could include it in the interface part? Here are my .as files, I'm so confused that I don't know where to start. Any code review / pointers would be great - https://www.box.com/s/9zsbu74dpzdj79abklxs

Comment: What you should do is create a mother class with a static parameter gameLayer (see the second part of my answer) and make every other class inherit from this one.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to apply this to my code. I'm confused because I've got functions and variables all over the shop. Being trying to make sense of it and sort it for most of the day but I'm just left scratching my head due to my inexperience.

Comment: Well... Don't tell the others I told you that: you can define gameLayer as `static` in Main.as and access it from anywhere with `Main.gameLayer`. This is not good practice.

Comment: I may just use that as I think it'll be too complicated to rework it the 'proper' way. My menu works now on my game but I need a way to stop the timer from automatically starting even when the user has not clicked 'Play Game'

Comment: One question, one problem. If you think this answer helped you with your problem, validate it and create a new question.

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried and the problems I'm having

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear enough. Once an answer is validated, it means the subject is closed. Only post here unitary questions about problems other people may have, the point of SO is to be a database of problems-solutions, this is not a "help me with my project until it works" forum.